# Duration of a Continuously Compounding Investment

Tags: continuity, finance

I have been asked to create a formula for the duration, 'd' of a continuously compounding investment for the time interval 0 <= t <= T.

I know that the 'force of interest' $\delta$ = ln(1+i), which means that $(1+i)^t$ = e^$\delta$t.

I also know that in order to create this formula, we will need to remove the summation signs and replace them with integrals, and the series of payments will be replaced with a function p(t).

From these basic ideas, I am at a loss of where to go next. I would definitely appreciate some more explanation and a push in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to go would be to solve the integral directly and have a closed form formula for your function. 
$e^{-\delta t}$ usually integrates very well :)
(with $t e^{-\delta t}$  usually integrating by parts!)

Comment: Thanks! I've just recently started working with duration, so I'm not sure that I understand how this correlates to the non-continuously compounding formula for duration. That is to say, I don't even really know how to connect the two to draw out the new formula. Any ideas?

Comment: You can see the duration as
1 - the mean point of the investment
2 - the impact of the change in $\delta$

mathematically, both countinuous and discrete have the very same meaning. Using countinous $\delta$ is usually easier for computational purposes (as discrete number math are way harder in general that countinuous). it also help when you are tring to evaluate more complicated stuff

Comment: Gotcha! I've come up with the equation d=p(t)/$\delta$ * (e^ $\delta$T - 1 - $\delta$T) all divided by p(t) e^$\delta$T - 1. Is this what you were getting at? I'm still very shaky on this but I believe it may work.

Comment: i actually suck with integrals by part so i use https://www.symbolab.com/solver/indefinite-integral-calculator/%5Cint%20xe%5E%7B%5Ctheta%20x%7Ddx/?origin=button but you have to understand that the duration is the variation of the price of your product in function. so you have to integrate the price as well!